# Increase container size + show DIV

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to increase the size of a container and show a div.... the code seems okay so I'm not sure why it doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas what may be wrong? Thanks a lot :)

http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/wXyDq/3/

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".container").width(300px);
  $('.left').slideLeft(200);


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".container").width(300);
  $('.left').show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 1000);
});
```

- Removed px from width.
- There no function known as `slideLeft()`. Replaced with `show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 1000)`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXyDq/7/).

Comment: Thanks Sahil! However, the 'left' still does not slide out for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/wXyDq/6/

Answer (score 5):

You've got a syntax error:

```
$(".container").width(300px);
                      ^    ^--- missing quotes
```

Anything other than a "pure" number must be surrounded by quotes, as they're strings - not numbers. Try `'300px'` instead.

Comment: Cool thank you! However, the 'left' still does not slide out for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/wXyDq/6/

Answer (score 3):

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $(".container").width(300);
   $('.left').slideLeft(200);
});
```

Should work. 300px does not exist like that. It's either `300` or `"300px"`

Comment: Cool thank you Py! However, the 'left' still does not slide out for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/wXyDq/6/

Comment: Maybe it's because `slideLeft` is not defined. (jQuery has only `slideUp` and `slideDown` by default)